# Large scale video conferencing

Tags: video, streaming, webvideos

Is there any way to providing video conference supporting large number of participants in conference (around 2000). The conference will be held in future and I should guaranty the performance. What is System Requirements for server. 
Does anybody test "Lync Server 2013", "apache-openmeeting" or "BigBlueButton"?

Comment: Do all the users have to be able to send video or just the presenters?  Whatever you use would have to be able to select a user to present at any given time and have the video feed only sent on request or the data rates involved would become completely impossible to sustain.  You probably want to look more into remote presentation software than video conferencing software since video conferencing tends to be more of an everyone sees everyone kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've messed with BBB, though no where close to those numbers.  As the presenter, you can prohibit participants from sharing their video or audio, making it a one way presentation.

I have a gut feeling though, that the server requirements would be significant for that many participants.  We ran it on an old HP G3 and it worked , but slow for a dozen participants.

From their [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_minimum_hardware_requirements_for_the_BigBlueButton):

> **What are the minimum hardware requirements for the BigBlueButton
>   Server** As a minimum, we recommend you run BigBlueButton on a dedicated
>   quad-core machine with at least 4 GB of memory and a 2.6+ Ghz
>   processor.
>
> We recommend installing BigBlueButton on Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit/64-bit on
>   the server (see Installing BigBlueButton).
>
> While the BigBlueButton VM is a good way to try out the system, we
>   recommend you run BigBlueButton on a dedicated server to reduce audio
>   lag. In a virtual environment, the BigBlueButton VM gets only a
>   portion of the host's CPU, and any lag in the CPU cycles can translate
>   to lag in processing VoIP packets.
>
> **What are the minimum bandwidth requirements for the BigBlueButton
>   Server** You'll need good upstream and downstream bandwidth from the
>   server. We recommend (at least) 100 MBits/second bandwidth in both
>   directions.

Personally, I'd probably looking into a SaaS solution like Webex, GoToMeeting, or the like.  There are probably at least a half dozen solid options.  Without having done it before, I'd hate to have sole responsibility for a conference that big.